# Retrieveing video/audio duration using WindowsAPICodecPack and Shell

Tags: azure, fileinfo, httppostedfilebase, windows-api-code-pack

I have the following code to retrieve the duration of a video uploaded:

```
HttpPostedFileBase postedFileCopy = postedFile;
postedFileCopy.InputStream.Position = 0;
Stream stream = postedFile.InputStream;

LocalResource tempDirectory = RoleEnvironment.GetLocalResource("TempZipDirectory");
postedFile.SaveAs(tempDirectory.RootPath + @"\" + postedFile.FileName);

ShellFile so = ShellFile.FromFilePath(tempDirectory.RootPath + @"\" + postedFile.FileName);
string durationString;
double nanoseconds;                
double.TryParse(so.Properties.System.Media.Duration.Value.ToString(),out nanoseconds);

if (nanoseconds > 0)
{
  int totalSeconds = (int)Math.Round((nanoseconds / 10000000), 0);
  int seconds = totalSeconds % 60;
  int minutes = totalSeconds / 60;
  int hour = totalSeconds / (60 * 60);
  durationString = "" + hour + ":" + minutes + ":" + seconds;
}
else
{
  System.Diagnostics.EventLog.WriteEntry("Application", "BLANK DURATION STRING", System.Diagnostics.EventLogEntryType.Error);
  durationString = "00:00:00";
}
```

This works as expected on localhost but when put up to Azure storage it does not seem to be able to retrieve the details of the file. The

```
postedFile.SaveAs(tempDirectory.RootPath + @"\" + postedFile.FileName);
```

saves the upload to the directory so i can grab these details but no matter what i try I cant seem to get the nanoseconds returned when the storage is on azure. This is a deployed MVC application and the tempdirectory is stored on the C:/ drive of the server.

Answer (score 1):

The code you refer is using native (Shell) functions. As AzureWebSites is running as a high-density shared environment, your code runs into non-full-trust mode. Calls to native functions is restricted in Azure Web Sites, even if you scale to reserved mode instances.

**UPDATE**

The only way to get application executed under FULL TRUST is to use Web Role (for web projects) or Worker Role (for background tasks).

Read more about [cloud services here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/jj618299.aspx).

Comment: Is there any workaround that you could think of which would allow me to use this on Azure or should this be ruled out of the question as a solution? I have deployed the WindowsAPICodepack dll and the shell should these not run with the app as full trust?